# How to make form templates in visual basic 6?

Tags: vb6

I would like to make a template for all the forms I create in my visual basic 6 project, for example I want to put a header on all the forms that contains user name etc, I know in c# all I have to do is make the form with appropriate controls and make all other forms inherit from in, in visual basic 6 there does not seem to be a way to make a form inherit from another?

Comment: Create a new user control (header) and use it in all froms

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733595(v=vs.60).aspx)

> To create your own template, save the object that you want to use as a
>   template, then copy it to the appropriate subdirectory of the Visual
>   Basic Template directory. For example, to create a custom MyForm form
>   template, save a form named MyForm, then copy the MyForm.frm file to
>   the \VB\Template\Forms directory. When you select the Add Form command
>   from the Project menu, Visual Basic displays the MyForm template in
>   the Add Form dialog box...

So...design a form any way you want--with whatever code, controls, etc. Then save it and copy it to the `\VB\Template\Forms` directory.